# delete hours, minutes and secconds in age Unix PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I work on one project with PHP and Mysql and I need to calculate the ages but I need delete the hours, minutes and seconds part. Here is an example:

The date of birth 2018-03-06 17:35:00 but
I need 2018-03-06 00:00:00

Here is my code:

```
function FetchAgeCaduce($MaxDias=3){

    $fechaInicial = time();//date("Y-m-d");  

    $fecha = date("d/m/Y",$FechaFinal);
    $fechaInicial = strtotime("d/m/Y",$fecha);

    for ($i=0; $i<$MaxDias; $i++)  
    {  
        $Segundos = $Segundos + 86400;  
        $caduca = time()+$Segundos;//date("D",time()+$Segundos);  
        $var = date("D",$caduca);

        if ($var == "Sat")
        {  
            $i--;  
        }  
        else if ($var == "Sun")  
        {  
            $i--;
        }  
        else  
        {  
            $FechaFinal = time()+$Segundos;  
        }  
    }  

    return $FechaFinal;
}
```

How can I work on it to get the expected result?

Comment: im not sure what your asking, but dont manipulate dates as strings use the the date\time class https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

**The right way / The MySQL way:**

Store your data as `DATE` in MySQL, not `DATETIME`. `DATE` itself is described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). It does not store time, so you'll always have `00:00:00` as default.

**The less right way / The PHP way:**

Jay, Zeus, Freaking, K. Reist. Learn to use `DateTime` already, stop using `date`! It's like every second question here and noone learns `DateTime`!

Use it!

```
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d 00:00:00");
```

The output:

```
2018-03-06 00:00:00
```

P.S. `$FechaFinal` on line 5 is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date on either the application or database layer.

**Using MySQL**

You can use [MySQL DATE_FORMAT Function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/)
 to parse the date into the wanted format.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') dob;
```

See [**DEMO on SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/19309).

**Using PHP**

Say you don't want to format the date in the database layer, may be because you would need to use the time part in some other calculations. Use the [date functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) as illustrated below:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d 00:00:00");

//getting the expected date from the formatted string
$formateDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dt->format("Y-m-d 00:00:00"));
```